# chmod: changing permissions of 'datenbank': Operation not supported

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have a USB drive sitting in my raspberry pi and I'm trying to `sshfs` into the drive.

I already changed the permission of most files and directories on that drive but when I try to `chmod 777 datenbank` as root it responds with the error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'datenbank': Operation not supported
```

Comment: The usb drive probably has fat or ntfs filesystem which does not support unix permissions.

Comment: @pLumo oh okay thanks that could be the issue what filesystem should be used to avoid that issue? Optimally a solution that uses a filesystem that can be used on windows and unix

Comment: Any native Linux filesystem, like `ext3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the USB drive to be accessible on any Windows system without installing special drivers from another media first, then FAT32 and NTFS (and possibly exFAT) are your only options. None of those will support real unix permissions.

If your goal is just to store the files with their unix permissions intact, you could use `tar` or some other archiving tool to package the files and their permission information into a `tar.bz2` file or similar. On Windows, the common WinZip and freeware 7zip utilities will open `tar.bz2` files just fine.

If the files need to be immediately executable on the USB drive, then you can use the `umask=000` mount option to specify permissions for directories and files on the FAT or NTFS filesystem, but it's an all-or-nothing affair: with that option, **all** the files and directories on the filesystem will have permissions equivalent to `chmod 777`.